# program keeps crashing (Python + pygame

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I made a very simple animation in pygame but it keeps to keep crashing on me and I can't figure out for the life of my it's happening. I've looked over it countless times but I see nothing wrong it it. It should work.

The code I have goes as following:

```
import pygame
import random

#consants
SIZE = (800,600)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
BROWN = (139,69,19)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
MAX_SNOWFLAKES = 800

#functions
x_sun = -40
y_sun = 55

def sun():
    x_sun = -40
    y_sun = 55    
for i in range(1000000):
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for i in range(1):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (x_sun, y_sun), 40)
        x_sun +=1
        if x_sun > 640:
            x_sun = 0
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)


def snowman(x,y):
    #snowman body
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (x,y), 30)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (x,y+50),40)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (x, y+110), 50)

    #snowman arms+hands
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x+40, y+50), (x+75, y+50), 2.5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x-40, y+50), (x-75, y+50), 2.5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x+70, y+50), (x+75, y+45), 2.5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x-70, y+50), (x-75, y+45), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x-70, y+50), (x-75, y+55), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BROWN, (x+70, y+50), (x+75, y+55), 2)

    #draws eyes
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (x+10, y-10), 4)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (x-10, y-10), 4)
    pygame.display.flip()

#x and y list
xlist_snow = []
ylist_snow = []

#display screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

#makes x + y list for snowflake
for i in range(MAX_SNOWFLAKES):
    x_num = random.randint(0,MAX_SNOWFLAKES)
    xlist_snow += [x_num]
    y_num = random.randint(0,(MAX_SNOWFLAKES-200))
    ylist_snow += [y_num]

#loop to print out the snowflakes
for i in range(10000):
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    #animates snowflakes by moving them downwards
    for i in range(len(xlist_snow)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (xlist_snow[i], ylist_snow[i]), 3)
        ylist_snow[i] = ylist_snow[i]+1

        #resets ypos if it equals 0
        if ylist_snow[i] >= 600:
            ylist_snow[i] = 0


    pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (x_sun, y_sun), 40)

    x_sun += 1
    if x_sun > 600:
        x_sun = 0

    #snowman(300,300)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(50)




pygame.time.wait(3000)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? That would've been helpful.

Comment: I am not getting a window not responding error

Comment: Could you please explain yourself a bit better? Do you mean that you do not get a window when executing the Python script? Could you try to run the Python script in terminal, and write the output here?

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. I am getting a window not responding error***.

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself now, thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

If the code you provided us is the complete code, then you haven't told Python what BLACK, YELLOW, WHITE etc. is.

These can be used if you import everything from pygame.locals:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Comment: Actually, he isn't using the predefined versions of those constants that Pygame has, but he did define them under the section marked #constants

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code isn't checking for events or doing anything during your time.wait(3000) part. You need to have a loop that checks for events while it's waiting